# syntax for cgaffinetransformconcat in swift 3?

Tags: swift3, xcode8, cgaffinetransform

**what is syntax for CGAffineTransformConcat in swift 3?**

because on using it shows the error:

> use of unresolved identifier "CGAffineTranformConcat"

please help me somebody

Comment: Have you read apple document for the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Swift 3 it is changed to [`concatenating(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform/1455996-concatenating). So you need to write it like this way.

```
let newTransform = transform1.concatenating(transform2)
```